# Force btrfs to allocate unallocated space

Tags: linux, partitioning, btrfs

My programs are complaining there is not enough space left on my btrfs RAID1. However, I seem to be unable to allocate more space.

```
sudo btrfs filesystem resize 1:max /mnt
sudo btrfs filesystem resize 2:max /mnt
```

seems to do nothing. When I display my usage I get loads of unallocated space. According to my research this is expected as btrfs takes the responsibility of allocating space. However, it does not seem to do so. How can I force more space to be allocated? The used amount seems to be wrong as well it seems. I should have 2,71 GiB of free space on data but actually 0 are available using `df -h` or any applications that want to write on the disk.

```
$ sudo btrfs fi usage /mnt
Overall:
    Device size:                  14.55TiB
    Device allocated:            854.06GiB
    Device unallocated:           13.72TiB
    Device missing:                  0.00B
    Used:                        847.88GiB
    Free (estimated):              6.86TiB      (min: 6.86TiB)
    Data ratio:                       2.00
    Metadata ratio:                   2.00
    Global reserve:              512.00MiB      (used: 0.00B)

Data,RAID1: Size:425.00GiB, Used:422.19GiB
   /dev/sda      425.00GiB
   /dev/sdd      425.00GiB

Metadata,RAID1: Size:2.00GiB, Used:1.75GiB
   /dev/sda        2.00GiB
   /dev/sdd        2.00GiB

System,RAID1: Size:32.00MiB, Used:80.00KiB
   /dev/sda       32.00MiB
   /dev/sdd       32.00MiB

Unallocated:
   /dev/sda        6.86TiB
   /dev/sdd        6.86TiB
```

**EDIT:** 
After deleting 20GiB of data on /dev/sda `df -h` suddenly returns 6.9T of free space instead of 0. If anyone could explain what the heck is going on I'd be grateful.

Comment: I use Btrfs, no RAID though. I had similar symptoms with `df` and "no space left on device". Fixed with `btrfs balance start`. See `man btrfs-balance`. Yes, this helped me in a single-device setup. I'm not sure it will help you, therefore just a comment.